# Retrieve data from scheduled task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

We're trying to collect the mapped drives of a user that is logged on to a Windows 7 client. To do this we need to create a scheduled task and have it run as that user. This works fine but the problem is on retrieving the data from the scheduled task.

**Code**

```
   Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    $User = 'John'
    $Script = 'C:\Users\' + $User + '\AppData\Local\Temp' + '\Script.ps1'
    $File = 'C:\Users\' + $User + '\AppData\Local\Temp' + '\Data.txt'


    $Code = {
        $User = 'John'
        $File = 'C:\Users\' + $User + '\AppData\Local\Temp' + '\Data.txt'
        Get-WmiObject -Class win32_mappedlogicaldisk | Select-Object Name, ProviderName | 
            Export-Csv $File -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
    }

    $Code | Set-Content $Script -Encoding utf8

    schtasks /create /RL HIGHEST /SC ONCE /ST 23:00 /TN "Test" /TR "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File '$Script'" /RU "$env:USERDNSDOMAIN\$User"
    schtasks /run /TN "Test"
    schtasks /delete /F /TN "Test"

    for ($i = 0; $i -le 5; $i++) {
        if (Test-Path $File) {
            Import-Csv $File
            Break
        }
        else {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }
    }

} -ComputerName $Computer
```

The problem seems to be retrieving the `Data.txt` from the users `$ENV:Temp` folder. It seems like a bit of a repetitive thing, is there not a cleaner way of doing this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Write the data to a share on a server?

Comment: Thx for the tip! U just thought there was a better way. Because now one needs to check when the file is present with a wait time on it.

Comment: Are you going to run this on a domain joined computer? If so there are much easier ways of doing this..

Comment: Yes, on a domain joined machine. The problem however lies in the fact to find the mapped drives of the logged on user, not the user that initiated the script from the server.

Comment: For scheduling, you might want to look into PSScheduledJob. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/psscheduledjob/psscheduledjob?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

As it is a non interactive script, I'd use the same approach, just with a shortened version of the wait loop:

```
while (!(Test-Path $File)) { Start-Sleep 1 }

Import-Csv $File
```

A bit more elegant, but essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like the below as a [Login Script](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770908(v=ws.11).aspx).

```
$File = "\\server\share\$($env:username).csv"

if (!(Test-Path $File)) {
    Get-WmiObject -Class win32_mappedlogicaldisk | Select-Object Name, ProviderName | Export-Csv $File -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
}
```

As it's a login script it will run in the users context (and get only their mapped drives) and will write files to a central share rather than their local drive so it will be much easier for you to get the data.

If you want another sample you can move/delete the files as appropriate, or remove the `Test-Path` check and add `-Append` to `Export-Csv` and it'll keep logging drives to the file at every logon.